# Get distincts values sql server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server

My problem is...
I Have this distinct table result
Table 1: 
`SELECT DISTINCT (CONCAT(ACCT , DOC)) as ACCTDOC FROM AuxTable`

```
ACCTDOC
xxx123
yyy456
```

2 rows

When I group by for another field I get this result:
Table 2:
`SELECT DISTINCT(CONCAT(ACCT,DOC))) as ACCTDOC, GENDER FROM AuxTable group by  ACCT,DOC,GENDER`

```
ACCTDOC GENDER
xxx123  M
xxx123  F
yyy456  M
```

3 rows

How to get just one line in this second table that matchs with table one. **I must keep the Gender field**. Is that possible?
Can I show the difference between table 1 and table 2?

My expect result is

```
ACCTDOC GENDER
xxx123  M
yyy456  M
```

Comment: Please show us raw data from the table, and also your expected results.

Comment: Hi Rafael, please [edit] your question and include the query you tried as well.

Comment: If you must keep the Gender information, you need to choose what gender are you going to select in case there is more than one option.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function!!! It's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and works on the whole selected rows. Skip those extra parentheses and simply write `SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(ACCT , DOC) as ACCTDOC FROM AuxTable` to make code clearer.

Comment: You rarely never combine `SELECT DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`, since the `GROUP BY` eliminates duplicates.

Comment: I know jarlh, but I have to. First of all, in my project, I have to count all Client (primary key is ACCT and DOC) Distinctly. Then I have to Clean all data, same client must not content 2 gender. In my front end I must to show how many Gender all data contains (so I have to group by data)... In the end, the number of rows in first case doesnt match with second

Comment: How should the database know that you want `M` rather than `F` in the gender column for `xxx123` in your example? Is the rule "show an M if at least one row has M, otherwise show an F?" Are those the only two possibilities for that column? Can it contain NULLs? Or perhaps the rule is something else, like "show the gender of whichever row is older based on some date column"?

Comment: Hi IMSoP, Thanks for trying help me. I just want the first gender that appers...I'm working in migration process, i dont want to create a function to handle this table

Answer (score 1):

I would never use distinct but always formulate the group by clause, distinct is virtually a dirty group by what does not output identical rows.

in order to communicate the column gender you have to form an aggregate here, e.g. with STRING_AGG (see aggregate / string functions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Example:

```
DECLARE @TableTest TABLE
    (ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
     ACCT VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
     DOC VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
     GENDER VARCHAR(10) NULL)

INSERT INTO @TableTest
  (ACCT,
   DOC,
   GENDER) 
VALUES
  ('xxx',
   '123',
   'M'),
  ('xxx',
   '123',
   'F'),
  ('yyy',
   '456',
   'M')

SELECT CONCAT(tt.ACCT, tt.DOC) as ACCTDOC,
      --tt.ACCT,
      --tt.DOC,
      STRING_AGG(tt.GENDER,'/') AS Genders
FROM   @TableTest AS tt
GROUP BY tt.ACCT,
        tt.DOC
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't have test data to try it out, but I hope the following query works for you:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table2 AS t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM Table1 AS t1 
    WHERE t1.ACCT = t2.ACCT AND t1.DOC = t2.DOC
)
```

For every row in Table2 you check if the same row does not appear in Table1 using the two specified columns. A note though; it only shows the missing entries from table 1 (which I assume is what you want).